# How to print all DirectorNames or ProducerNames etc alphabetically reading from a text file

Tags: java, list, collections, indexof

```
public void alphabeticalListing()
{
    BufferedReader br = null;
    List<String> lineList = new ArrayList<String>();
    try
    {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(wishlistname + ".txt"));
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine())!=null)
        {
            lineList.add(line);
        }
        Collections.sort(lineList);
        for(String output : lineList) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The file Contains Movie Details...
Example:

MovieName:DirectorName:ProducerName:Rating:Review

Terminator: Arfath: Khalid : 8 : VeryGood

Hangover  : John  : Lucas  : 7 : NotBad

Jumanji   : Rock  : Brock  : 9 : Good

I want to select ProducerName Column and do SOP in alphabetically like,

Output:

Brock

Khalid

Lucas

Answer (score 0):

You can use java `Compartor` for sorting by creating `Movie` as model `class`. You can achieve this using below code:

```
public static void readDataFromFile(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    File file = new File(filePath); 
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file); 

    while (sc.hasNextLine())
    {
        String txtLine = sc.nextLine();

        //Extract data from single from txt file row
        String[] data = txtLine.split(":");

        Movie movie = new Movie(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4]);

        //Add to movies list
        movies.add(movie);

    }

    System.out.println("Unsorted-----------");
    System.out.println(movies);

    System.out.println("Sorting by director-----------");
    Collections.sort(movies, new DirectorSorter());
    System.out.println(movies);

    System.out.println("Sorting by producer-----------");
    Collections.sort(movies, new ProducerSorter());
    System.out.println(movies);
}

public static class Movie
{
    private String name;
    private String director;
    private String producer;
    private String rating;
    private String review;

    public Movie(){}

    public Movie(String name, String director, String producer, String rating, String review){
        this.name = name;
        this.director = director;
        this.producer = producer;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.review = review;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDirector() {
        return director;
    }

    public void setDirector(String director) {
        this.director = director;
    }

    public String getProducer() {
        return producer;
    }

    public void setProducer(String producer) {
        this.producer = producer;
    }

    public String getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(String rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public String getReview() {
        return review;
    }

    public void setReview(String review) {
        this.review = review;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Movie : " + name + " - " + director + " - " + producer + " - " + rating + " - " + review + "\n";
    }
}


public static class DirectorSorter implements Comparator<Movie>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Movie o1, Movie o2) {
        return o1.getDirector().compareTo(o2.getDirector());
    }
}

public static class ProducerSorter implements Comparator<Movie>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Movie o1, Movie o2) {
        return o1.getProducer().compareTo(o2.getProducer());
    }
}
```